# How to declare a service in global.d.ts file in NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a NodeJS Express project, that include a service called UtilServices.ts
I want to declare this service in global.d.ts file to be able to use it globally in the project without need to import it in each place it's used in.

I tried to do that but I got an error during runtime that service is not defined, although there is nor build error.

The following is my code:

global.d.ts file:

```
import { UtilService } from './src/services/utilService';
declare global {
    var UtilService: UtilService;
}
```

here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
"files": ["global.d.ts", "./src/app.ts"]
}
```

And I call service directly where I want to use it, as following:

```
UtilService.doSomeThing();
```

I got an error during runtime that UtilService is not defined, although there is nor build error.

I want to know if there any error in my code or any missed code or configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UtilService` property on the `global` object and assign the `UtilService` object to it.

A working example uses `node v14.19.3`:

`services/utilService.ts`:

```
const UtilService = {
  doSomething() {
    return 'do something'
  }
}

export { UtilService }
```

`setup.ts`:

```
import { UtilService } from './services/utiService';

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      UtilService: typeof UtilService
    }
  }
}

global.UtilService = UtilService;
```

`a.ts`:

```
export const run = () => {
  console.log('a: ', global.UtilService.doSomething())
}
```

`b.ts`:

```
export const run = () => {
  console.log('b: ', global.UtilService.doSomething())
}
```

`main.ts`:

```
import './setup';
import * as a from './a';
import * as b from './b';

a.run();
b.run();
```

Run and output:

```bash
⚡  npx ts-node ./main.ts                                                                                     
a:  do something
b:  do something
```

package versions:

```json
"typescript": "^5.0.4",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
```